# Hamcrest compare collections

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I'm trying to compare 2 lists:

```
assertThat(actual.getList(), is(Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(expectedList)));
```

But idea

```
java: no suitable method found for assertThat(java.util.List<Agent>,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends model.Agents>>)
method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>) is not applicable
  (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends model.Agents>> conforms to formal parameter type org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>)
method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(java.lang.String,T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>) is not applicable
  (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

How should I write it?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

If you want to assert that the two lists are identical, don't complicate things with Hamcrest:

```
assertEquals(expectedList, actual.getList());
```

If you really intend to perform an order-insensitive comparison, you can call the `containsInAnyOrder` varargs method and provide values directly:

```
assertThat(actual.getList(), containsInAnyOrder("item1", "item2"));
```

(Assuming that your list is of `String`, rather than `Agent`, for this example.)

If you really want to call that same method with the contents of a `List`:

```
assertThat(actual.getList(), containsInAnyOrder(expectedList.toArray(new String[expectedList.size()]));
```

Without this, you're calling the method with a single argument and creating a `Matcher` that expects to match an `Iterable` where *each element* is a `List`. This can't be used to match a `List`.

That is, you can't match a `List<Agent>` with a `Matcher<Iterable<List<Agent>>`, which is what your code is attempting.

Comment: +1 for the "If you really want to call that same method with the contents of a List". Sadly I couldn't get that solved myself. Specially that there is a constructor that takes in a collection.

Comment: @Tim Not quite; `containsInAnyOrder` requires that *all* elements are present, so that first assertion will fail. See `hasItems` if you want to check that *at least* those elements are present.

Comment: If you use containsInAnyOrder, you should first make sure both lists have the same size... If `actual.getList()` happens to contain `"item1", "item3", "item2"`, the test will pass and maybe you want to make sure it only contains the items listed... In that case you could use `assertThat(actual.getList().size(), equalTo(2));` before the containsInAnyOrder, this way you make sure both lists have the same contents.

Comment: @Martin you're thinking of `hasItems`. The extra check is unnecessary here. See the comment to Tim above, and also [How do Hamcrest's hasItems, contains and containsInAnyOrder differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33840531/733345)

Comment: **Kotlin users**: don't forget to add the spread operator (`*expectedList.toTypedArray()`) when passing an array as varargs!

Comment: Can I draw your attention to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107741/hamcrest-matchers-containsinanyorder-does-not-work

I tried the above and was dealing with a significantly more complex list of items to match - the answer here resolved me issue

Answer (score 83):

```
List<Long> actual = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L);
List<Long> expected = Arrays.asList(2L, 1L);
assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));
```

Shorter version of @Joe's answer without redundant parameters.

Answer (score 50):

To complement @Joe's answer:

Hamcrest provides you with four main methods to match a list:

`contains` Checks for matching all the elements considering the order. If the list has more or fewer elements, it will fail

`containsInAnyOrder` Checks for matching all the elements, and it doesn't matter the order. If the list has more or fewer elements, will fail

`hasItems` Checks just for the specified objects it doesn't matter if the list has more

`hasItem` Checks just for one object it doesn't matter if the list has more

All of them can receive a list of objects and use the `equals` method for comparison or can be mixed with other matchers like @borjab mentioned:

```
assertThat(myList , contains(allOf(hasProperty("id", is(7L)), 
                                   hasProperty("name", is("testName1")),
                                   hasProperty("description", is("testDesc1"))),
                             allOf(hasProperty("id", is(11L)), 
                                   hasProperty("name", is("testName2")),
                                   hasProperty("description", is("testDesc2")))));
```

http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(E...)
http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(java.util.Collection)
http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasItems(T...)

Comment: Great decision in case list items are not of primitive type.

Comment: Is there a type safe way of doing this?

Answer (score 21):

With existing Hamcrest libraries (as of v.2.0.0.0) you are forced to use Collection.toArray() method on your Collection in order to use containsInAnyOrder Matcher.
Far nicer would be to add this as a separate method to org.hamcrest.Matchers:

```
public static <T> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends T>> containsInAnyOrder(Collection<T> items) {
    return org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.<T>containsInAnyOrder((T[]) items.toArray());
}
```

Actually I ended up adding this method to my custom test library and use it to increase readability of my test cases (due to less verbosity).

Comment: Nice one, I will use this helper. The assert message here is more informative: it names the missing items one-by-one, not just: the list should be elem1, elem2, .. elem99, but I got elem1, elem2, ..., elem98 -- good luck finding the missing one.

Answer (score 5):

For list of objects you may need something like this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void test_returnsList(){

    arrange();
  
    List<MyBean> myList = act();
    
    assertThat(myList , contains(allOf(hasProperty("id",          is(7L)), 
                                       hasProperty("name",        is("testName1")),
                                       hasProperty("description", is("testDesc1"))),
                                 allOf(hasProperty("id",          is(11L)), 
                                       hasProperty("name",        is("testName2")),
                                       hasProperty("description", is("testDesc2")))));
}
```

Use [containsInAnyOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(org.hamcrest.Matcher...)) if you do not want to check the order of the objects.

P.S. Any help to avoid the warning that is suppresed will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the `Object`s in your list have `equals()` defined on them. Then

```
assertThat(generatedList, is(equalTo(expectedList)));
```

works.

Answer (score -6):

To compare two lists with the order preserved (strict order) use.

```
assertThat(actualList, contains("item1","item2"));
```

If we want to compare without a specific order we can use below command

```
assertThat(collection, containsInAnyOrder("item1","item2"));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It partially does.

Comment: @rvazquezglez What do you mean? Why do you say that? The result of the method is right in my environment.

Comment: @niaomingjian The code is checking that the `actualList` contains the elements inside of `contains` matcher, that will fail if the elements are not in the same order and will fail too if it contains more elements or is missing one.

Comment: @rvazquezglez so the purpose of the code is to examine the exact equality(same lengths, values and order) in two lists, right?

Comment: @niaomingjian right, I added some other hamcrest methods in a separate answer for when you want to compare other aspects of a list and its contents