# AssertEquals 2 Lists ignore order

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, junit, assertion

That should be really simple question I believe. But somehow I can't find answer in Google.

Assume that I have 2 Lists of Strings. First contains **"String A" and "String B"**, second one contains **"String B" and "String A"** (notice difference in order). I want to test them with **JUnit** to check whether they contains **exactly the same** Strings.

Is there any assert that checks equality of Strings that ignore order? For given example org.junit.Assert.assertEquals throws AssertionError

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[String A, String B]> but was:<[String B, String A]>
```

Work around is to sort Lists firstly and then pass them to assertion. But I want my code to be as simple and clean as possible.

I use **Hamcrest 1.3**, **JUnit 4.11**, **Mockito 1.9.5**.

Comment: `list1.removeAll(list2)` should leave `list1` empty. I guess you can build on this to get what you want.

Comment: `containsAll` and `removeAll` are `O(n²)` for lists while sorting them and test for equality is `O(nlogn)`. `Collections.sort(list1); Collections.sort(list2); assertTrue(list1.equals(list2));` is also clean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hamcrest compare collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624592/hamcrest-compare-collections)

Comment: @SudoRahul - What if you do not want to modify a list by removing all ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - Since that was not a constraint from the OP, I suggested that. But if that is a constraint, then the accepted answer for this question solves the problem at hand.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

As you mention that you use **[Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/)**,
So I would pick one of the collection Matchers

```java
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class CompareListTest {

    @Test
    public void compareList() {
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("String A", "String B");
        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("String B", "String A");
        
        assertThat("List equality without order", 
            actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: See also my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38262680/297710 which shows, how to improve Hamcrest matchers and avoid ".toArray()" in every assert with containsInAnyOrder

Answer (score 73):

You can use [List.containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) with JUnit's assertTrue to check that the first list contains every element from the second one, and vice versa.

```
assertEquals(expectedList.size(), actualList.size());
assertTrue(expectedList.containsAll(actualList));
assertTrue(actualList.containsAll(expectedList));
```

Hint:
This doesn't work with **duplicates** in the lists.

Comment: I accept this one because the code is the most clean I think.

Comment: @kukis See the comments in leventov's answer.

Comment: True that. Don't really know which answer is correct.

Comment: @kukis It depends, do you want to check for duplicates?

Comment: Yes, of course. 2 given Lists must be exactly the same just ignoring order.

Comment: @kukis Check ZouZou's comment on your question then.

Comment: ..might include `assertEquals(first.size(), second.size())` ..then it should work as expected

Comment: This doesn't work with duplicates in the list.  Here's an example to demonstrate:
`List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b");`
`List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "b");`
`assertEquals(list1.size(), list2.size());`
`assertTrue(list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1));`

In this example, both assertions fail to detect that the lists are actually different.  @AlexWorden mentions Apache Commons Collections' CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection() which, for this example, correctly detects that the collections are not equal.

Comment: I hope the edit here would make more sense to use this method for comparison.

Comment: @nullpointer - Looks like you misunderstood desilvai's comment. Roberto's answer is still wrong even after your edits. Please revert the edits and downvote roberto's answer.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Could you elaborate whats still wrong there?

Comment: @nullpointer - The assertions you added in your edit will fail to compare array lists correctly. To see it happening, run the code in selivai's comment.

Comment: Another downside I experienced with this approach is that if the assertion fails, you do not get to see why (which objects were missing in the arrays). The `assertThat` with `containsInAnyOrder` does support this feature.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution that avoids quadratic complexity (iterating over the lists multiple times). This uses the Apache Commons CollectionUtils class to create a Map of each item to a frequency count itself in the list. It then simply compares the two Maps.

```
Assert.assertEquals("Verify same metrics series",
    CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap(expectedSeriesList),
    CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap(actualSeriesList));
```

I also just spotted CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection that claims to do exactly what is being requested here...

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html

Answer (score 11):

With AssertJ, `containsExactlyInAnyOrder()` or `containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf()` is what you need :

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareListTest {

    @Test
    public void compareListWithTwoVariables() {
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("String A", "String B");
        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("String B", "String A");
        Assertions.assertThat(actual)
                  .containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(expected);
    }

    @Test
    public void compareListWithInlineExpectedValues() {
        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("String B", "String A");
        Assertions.assertThat(actual)
                  .containsExactlyInAnyOrder("String A", "String B");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    Collections.sort(excepted);
    Collections.sort(actual);
    assertEquals(excepted,actual);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix I would check both ways:

```
assertTrue(first.containsAll(second));
assertTrue(second.containsAll(first));
```

And trying with a situation where the number of the same elements is different (e.g. 1, 1, 2 and 1, 2, 2) I didn't get false positives.

Comment: Your code still fails. See this example -  @Test
 public void test1() {
  List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b");
  List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "b");
  Assert.assertTrue(list1.containsAll(list2));
  Assert.assertTrue(list2.containsAll(list1));
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ListAssert](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/ListAssert.html) that comes in junit-addons jar.

```
ListAssert.assertEquals(yourList, Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Im late to the party but here's my solution using Junit only. Any thoughts are welcome.

```
List<String> actual = new ArrayList<>();
actual.add("A");
actual.add("A");
actual.add("B");

List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();
actual.add("A");
actual.add("B");
actual.add("B");

//Step 1: assert for size
assertEquals(actual.size(), expected.size());

//Step 2: Iterate
for(String e: expected){
    assertTrue(actual.contains(e));
    actual.remove(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that solution by Roberto Izquierdo has quadratic complexity in general. Solution on HashSets always has linear complexity:

```
assertTrue(first.size() == second.size() &&
        new HashSet(first).equals(new HashSet(second)));
```

Comment: That approach won't work. If first is ("String A") and second is ("String A", "String A") they are not the same lists.

Comment: You can't check the size. If first is `("s1", "s2", "s3" ,"s1")` and second is `("s2", "s1", "s3" ,"s2");` they are not the same list.

Comment: @ZouZou the accepted solution has the same problem. You suggested the only really correct solution. If you make an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: @ZouZou They are not the same list, but they contain exactly the same Strings. OP, clarify?. Also, make it an answer and I will upvote too :) didn't think of that.

Comment: This is still not correct for all cases ("A", "A", "B") will compare as equal to ("A", "B", "B")

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the other answers either reference 3rd party utils, are incorrect, or are inefficient.

Here's a O(N) vanilla solution in Java 8.

```
public static void assertContainsSame(Collection<?> expected, Collection<?> actual)
{
    assert expected.size() == actual.size();

    Map<Object, Long> counts = expected.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                item -> item,
                Collectors.counting()));

    for (Object item : actual)
        assert counts.merge(item, -1L, Long::sum) != -1L;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the updated hamcrest assertions

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class TestCompareCollection {


    @Test
    public void compareList() {
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("String A", "String B");
        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("String B", "String A");

        assertThat("List is not matching",
                actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));

    }

}
```