# TestNG - How to assert that two lists are equal ignoring order?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, equals, assertion

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807328/assertequals-2-lists-ignore-order) for JUnit but couldn't find for TestNG.

Comment: Alternatively shouldn't just the [following assertEquals](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.12-g0ef9cdb-153/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-) suffice for comparison - `assertEquals(list1,list2);`
? `Object` comparison.

Comment: and do you actually need testng to do it? I like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22807363/1746118) instead the most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent as good as found in the Hamcrest library but you could transform each of the lists to an array and the use:

```
public static void assertEqualsNoOrder(Object[] actual,
                                       Object[] expected)
```

as per javadoc:

> Asserts that two arrays contain the same elements in no particular
>   order