# Hamcrest: Compare two custom class object collections

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I've two `Collection<Audit>` collections:

```
Collection<Audit> pendingAudits;
Collection<Audit> olderAudits;
```

So, I need to compare all `pendingAudits` elements are in `olderAudits`.

In order to compare them, it's necessary to compare that each `audit.getId().equals(other.getId())`.

Please, take in mind I'm not able to override `Audit.equals` or `Audit.hashCode`. It's a third-party class.

I guess I need to create a custom inline `Matcher`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hamcrest compare collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624592/hamcrest-compare-collections)

Comment: Please read the other question and yes, you obviously need to override `equals` and `hashCode`

Comment: Please, read post again. Related question is comparing plain strings!

Comment: That's right and your edited ___important___ information into question after I've linked the question. Thank you for hiding crucial information.

Comment: I do agree with @Tom. Since you would like to know how to compare two collections, and not to use the Hamcrest the way you should... here: `return first.size() == second.size() && first.stream().noneMatch(f -> second.stream().anyMatch(s -> f.getId() != s.getId()));`

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you want to give assertj a try, you could benefit from its [custom comparison strategy](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy)

```
@Test
void myTest() {
    Collection<Audit> pendingAudits = ...
    Collection<Audit> olderAudits = ...

    Comparator<Audit> byId = Comparator.comparing(Audit::getId);
    assertThat(olderAudits).usingElementComparator(byId).containsAll(pendingAudits);
}
```