# Hamcrest: test that an Iterable contains all elements of another Iterable

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I've got a test that looks something like this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;

private final List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>("abc","xyz");

@Test
public void myTest() {
  List<String> result = underTest();

  assertThat(result, containsInAnyOrder(expected));
```

This test fails, because it expects `result` to contain `expected`.  What I'm trying to do is test that `result` contains *each element in* `expected`.  Is there a Matcher for this in hamcrest, or would I need to write one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624592/hamcrest-compare-collections

Comment: yep, that's it. Thanks!